# Do I have to create a new web driver object whenever the test navigates to another page?

Tags: javascript, node.js, testing, selenium, selenium-webdriver

This is the code I'm using to test if after logging in, the user is able to move to another page. But the test keeps failing, telling me `NoSuchElementError: no such element`.

```
var webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver');

var driver = new webdriver.Builder().
   withCapabilities(webdriver.Capabilities.chrome()).
   build();

driver.get('localhost:3012');
var loginForm = driver.findElement(webdriver.By.id('login'));
loginForm.findElement(webdriver.By.name('email')).sendKeys('abcd@abcd.com');
loginForm.findElement(webdriver.By.name('password')).sendKeys('1234');
loginForm.submit();

var waiting = false;
var finished = false;
driver.wait(function() {
    if (driver.findElement(webdriver.By.id('welcomeMsg')) !== null) {
        driver.findElement(webdriver.By.id('problemListHeading')).click();
        if (!waiting) {
            waiting = true;

            driver.wait(function() {
                if (driver.findElement(webdriver.By.id('problemList'))) {

                            finished = true;
                            return true;


                }
            });
        }
        return finished;
    }
}, 1000);

driver.quit();
```

Here is a part of the error log:

```
==== async task ====
WebDriver.findElement(By.id("problemList"))
    at webdriver.WebDriver.schedule (/media/Data1/Projects/Assignments/SE_Lab/ninja-store/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver/webdriver.js:267:15)
```

Comment: Are you sure that the element is loaded in the DOM? Also, check if the element is not inside a frame/iframe. Please post the HTML code if possible.

Comment: No. A common strategy is to implement the Page Object model whereby you pass the `driver` instance around the various page objects. (Although I don't know the WebDriverJS library all that well, so it might be more difficult to do so).

Answer (score 0):

When you say navigate to another page, does it mean a new browser? If so, you may have to switch browser using the below snippet.

```
String winHandleBefore = driver.getWindowHandle();
        for(String winHandle : driver.getWindowHandles()){
            driver.switchTo().window(winHandle);
        }
driver.switchTo().window(winHandleBefore);
```

Comment: no, not a new browser. just a different page when I click on a hyperlink.

Answer (score 0):

Webdriver's `findElement` method will throw an exception if it does not find the element. Try using `isElementPresent` instead. So something like:

```
return driver.wait(function () {
    return driver.isElementPresent(webdriver.By.name('problemList'), 5000)
});
```